# SharePoint KQL syntax for YesNo field

Tags: sharepoint

What's the correct syntax for querying a SharePoint YesNo (boolean) field using SharePoint Keyword Query Language (KQL)?
I can't find any examples in [KQL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference) and don't have a quick way of testing this either.

```
IsRetained:Yes
IsRetained:'Yes'
IsRetained:True
IsRetained:true
IsRetained:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, you can use the following keywords to search:

```
IsRetained:True
IsRetained:true
IsRetained:1
```

IsRetained:True
[image]

IsRetained:true
[image]
IsRetained:1
[image]

If searching using "`IsRetained:Yes`" or "`IsRetained:'Yes'`"
[image]